# Can't enable copy/paster between Kali virtualbox and Windows host

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, kali-linux

I am trying to enable copy/paste between a Kali Linux virtualbox machine and a Windows host machine. First from the virtual machine advanced settings, I enabled `bidirectional` choice at both shared clipboard and drag and drop. Then I went to the virtualbox `Devices-> Insert Guest Additions CD image`. Then a CD icon appeared in the desktop. When I try to open the CD icon and click the `Run Software` button at the top right corner, I get an error saying `Unable to locate the program`. See the screen shot below. Can you help me how to enable copy/paste between the two machines?

[image]

**Update:**
I followed the first comment's instructions. I got this problem:
[image]

Comment: @None Use `apt-get update; apt-get upgrade`.

Answer (score 0):

If you see the cd icon on your desktop it means the guest additions are on.Instead of copying and pasting files and folders between host , guest and vice versa you can mount a sharing folder in which you can add everything you want to be shared between the two OS's.As far as i know this is one of the advantages the guest additions offer.Another one is so your virtual machine screen resolution fits perfectly the monitor size without sidebars.All of the above while VTx is enabled.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This doesn't really answer the question OP asked, can you suggest how they might enable copy and paste instead?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check whether you have the mentioned entry in your sources.list located under `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

You should see an entry like this: `deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib`

For more information read [here](https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories).

Make sure that you have the latest dist upgrades by running
`(sudo) apt-get dist-upgrade`. For this action you might want to deactivate your antivirus on the host machine. You will be prompted with some questions you definetly should read carefully and decide wheter enable or disable this feature.
After installation completed you restart the VM.

Alternatively  run `(sudo) apt-get update && apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`.
If header installation failed you might want to check manually for applicable headers and install them by running `apt-cache search linux-headers` to list all available headers and install the desired one with `apt-get install linux-headers-<kernel-release>`.

Then try again running `(sudo) apt-get install -y virtualbox-guest-x11`.
Note: Like @dsstorefile alreade mentioned ther is no dash between virtual and box!